# How to merge two Consumer into one in Haskell Pipes?

Tags: haskell, pipe

I use Haskell stream processing library [pipes](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes) to write a command line tool. Each command line actions may output result to `stdout` and logs to `stderr` with `pipes` API.

I need `Consumer` which has type as `Consumer (Either String String) m r` to print chunk of data (`Left` to `stderr`, `Right` to `stdout`) with single `Consumer`.

#### Code I wrote (should be improved)

This function `consumeEither` doesn't have flexibility so I want to improve it.

```
consumeEither :: (MonadIO m) => Consumer (Either String String) m ()
consumeEither = do
  eitherS <- await
  case eitherS of
    (Left l)  -> for (yield l) (liftIO . (IO.hPutStrLn IO.stderr))
    (Right r) -> for (yiled r) (liftIO . putStrLn)
```

Furthermore it would be useful to provide a function which takes two `Consumer`s and merge them into one `Consumer`.

#### Question

*Does anybody know good example or implementation of the following interface?*

```
merge :: (Monad m) => Consumer a m r -> Consumer b m r -> Consumer (Either a b) m r
```

- 1st argument as `stderr`
- 2nd argument as `stdout`

#### Usage of the function

```hs
import           Pipes
import qualified Pipes.Prelude as P
import qualified System.IO as IO

stdoutOrErr :: Consumer (Either String String) IO ()
stdoutOrErr = merge (P.toHandle IO.stderr) P.stdoutLn
```

Thanks

Comment: I think you need the [`ArrowChoice` proxies](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes-3.2.0/docs/Control-Proxy-Prelude-Base.html#g:7). [Some discussion here](http://www.haskellforall.com/2013/03/pipes-32-listt-codensity-arrowchoice.html)

Comment: See `(+++)` in [pipes-extras](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes-extras-1.0.0/docs/Pipes-Extras.html#g:1) Keep in mind a `Consumer` is a `Pipe` (to nowhere), so `P.toHandle IO.stderr +++ P.stdoutLn :: MonadIO m => Pipe (Either String String) (Either b d) m ()` To get a `Consumer`, you would have to get rid of the `Left`s e.g with `>-> P.concat` or `>-> P.drain`  There are more robust and handsome ways of doing this with Folds.

Comment: Sorry, maybe that was more confusing than: `merge p q = p +++ q >-> P.concat` .  (Here, `P.concat` is acting like `Data.Either.rights`)

Comment: @rampion I found out that what I want to do is not "merging consumers" but "choose consumers". You gave me the point. I'll check it. Thanks.

Comment: @Michael concise combinator +++! It looks useful. I'll try it. Thanks.

Comment: @Michael would you like to write that up as an answer? :P

Answer (score 1):

(This is @Michael's answer, but I'd like to write it up here so we can move the question out of the unanswered queue for the Haskell tag.)

See `(+++)` in [pipes-extras](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes-extras-1.0.4/docs/Pipes-Extras.html). Keep in mind a `Consumer` is a `Pipe` (to nowhere), so `P.toHandle IO.stderr +++ P.stdoutLn :: MonadIO m => Pipe (Either String String) (Either b d) m ()`.

To get a `Consumer`, you would have to get rid of the `Lefts` e.g with `>-> P.concat` or `>-> P.drain`. There are more robust and handsome ways of doing this with `Fold`s.