# Using a single Haskell pipe to split HTTP content to two consumers

Tags: haskell, pipe

I can't really figure out whether some of [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16205440/haskell-pipes-and-branching) [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29932852/how-to-merge-two-consumer-into-one-in-haskell-pipes) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33464543/forking-the-streaming-flow-in-haskell-pipes) are similar enough to mine but I couldn't extract a solution out of them so I'm posting. Feel free to indicate to me otherwise.

I have a flow where I need to download a large CSV file, and 1) save it to disk, and 2) process it. I'd like to use Haskell pipes, with the [pipes-http](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes-http) and [pipes-csv](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes-csv) packages to do this.

The obvious way is to have two separate pipes: 1) web -> disk, and then 2) disk -> process. Is it possible to do another topology where the output from the web splits into two consumers, one that saves and the other that processes? I feel that this could be more elegant and possibly more efficient.

If so, how is the splitting done? Splitting of pipes is not mentioned anywhere in the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression "splitting the content between consumers" might be a little misleading; you want to send all bytes to each of two consumers. But `Pipes.Prelude.tee` turns any consumer into a Pipe, thus

```
producer >-> tee consumer1 >-> consumer2
```

feeds the producer to both of the consumers. But the particular case of writing to a file might be simplest with `Pipes.Prelude.chain`, rather than a consumer. `tee` and `chain` allow you to do something with each incoming value, before forwarding it along the pipeline. In this case I just write each successive chunk to a handle, before passing it along:

```
import Pipes
import Pipes.HTTP
import qualified Pipes.ByteString as PB 
import qualified Pipes.Prelude as P
import qualified System.IO as IO
import qualified Data.ByteString as B

main = do
    req <- parseUrl "https://www.example.com"
    m <- newManager tlsManagerSettings 
    withHTTP req m $ \resp -> 
      IO.withFile "file.txt" IO.WriteMode $ \h -> 
        runEffect $ responseBody resp >-> P.chain (B.hPut h) >-> PB.stdout
```

I ended the pipeline with `PB.stdout` where you would use `pipes-csv` materials. Using `tee`, I could as well have written

```
runEffect $ responseBody resp >-> P.tee (PB.toHandle h) >-> PB.stdout
```

for the last line. Where the 'consumers' can be viewed as folds, there is the apparatus of `Control.Foldl` for combining many folds together - and any number of other devices.